# Knockout Mapping reading JSON

Tags: json, jquery-plugins, knockout.js, getjson, knockout-mapping-plugin

Just starting with KnockOut Mapping to read some JSON (using Google Books API) , but can't seem to get it to work. No errors report, but nothing is displayed. Probably a simple issue I overlooked, but thanks for the review.

Markup....

```
<body>
<h2>Find Cat in the Hat</h2>
   <div>
        <input id="booksearch" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Volumes</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: model.items">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: model.id"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <input id="btnTest" type="button" value="button" />
</body>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
```

Jquery....

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Knockout Test

    $('#btnTest').click(function () {
        var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=the+Cat+In+The+Hat";

        var viewModel = {};
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            viewModel.model = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle to recreate your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [`$.getJSON` success callback](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) you will get back a JavaScript object not a JSON string:

> The success callback is passed the returned data, which is **typically a
>   JavaScript object or array as defined by the JSON structure and parsed
>   using the $.parseJSON() method**. It is also passed the text status of
>   the response

So you need to use `ko.mapping.fromJS(data);` method instead of `ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);`

Your fixed code should look like:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    viewModel.model = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

You also have an another issue in your view: `data-bind="text: model.id"` should be `data-bind="text: id"` you don't need the `model` there because inside the `foreach` you are in the context of `model.items`:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: model.items">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WuFrp/).

Comment: @nemesv have you considered querying mutliple searches ? NO , error : Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

Comment: @ProllyGeek I've never considered multiple searches, the original question was about how to properly parse the response with the mapping plugin and it was never occurred to me that you cannot execute the search twice (anyway the search in the demo only returns a fix list and not actually working). Of course the `ko.applyBindings` has to be called once and with some restructuring of the code (moving the `ko.applyBindings` to the DOM ready and using the mapping plugin a little bit differently) it could work: http://jsfiddle.net/mqna9nxg/

Comment: @nemesv have you tried multiple search on your example ?