# KnockoutJs : ko.mapping.fromJS and binding => how to do it properly?

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, mapping

I really am struggling with something that I thought was simple...

I am making a simple search-result table based on $.getJSON call, and want to keep my code as "generic" as possible.

In my (simplified) HTML :

```
<form id="searchForm">
(...)
    <button type="button" onclick="search()">Search</button>
</form>

(...)
<tbody data-bind="foreach: data">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: FOO"></td>
(...)
        <td data-bind="text: BAR"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Then in my javascript (in `script` tags lower in the page):

```
var search = function(){
    var form = $('#searchForm');
    $.getJSON("php/query/jsonQuery.php?jsonQuery=search", form.serialize(), function(jsonAnswer, textStatus) {
        console.log(jsonAnswer);
        if(typeof viewModel === 'undefined'){
            var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonAnswer);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        }
        else{
            ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonAnswer, viewModel);
        }
        $('#divResults').show();
//         console.log(viewModel)
    });
}
```

This works fine on the first "search" click... but not the following : `Error You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element`.

As you can guess, this very ugly "if" testing viewModel is a desperate attempt to get rid of that error.

I've tried many things but I just can't figure out how to do it properly...

I've read this [Knockout JS update view from json model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896922/knockout-js-update-view-from-json-model) and this [KnockoutJs v2.3.0 : Error You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710788/knockoutjs-v2-3-0-error-you-cannot-apply-bindings-multiple-times-to-the-same-e) but it didn't help me much... maybe because the search() function isn't called on load (and indeed shouldn't be).

Any KO master to give me a clue? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would be approaching what you are trying to accomplish.

```js
var searchService = {
  search: function(form, vmData) {
    //$.getJSON("php/query/jsonQuery.php?jsonQuery=search", form.serialize(), function(jsonAnswer, textStatus) {
      var jsonAnswer = [{
        FOO: "Item 1 Foo",
        BAR: "Item 1 Bar"
      }, {
        FOO: "Item 2 Foo",
        BAR: "Item 2 Bar"
      }]
      ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonAnswer, [], vmData);
      //})
    }
};

var PageViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.data = ko.observableArray();
  self.hasResults = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return self.data().length > 0;
  });

  self.search = function() {
    var form = $('#searchForm');
    searchService.search(form, self.data);
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new PageViewModel());
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<form id="searchForm">
  <button type="button" data-bind="click:search">Search</button>
</form>
<div data-bind="visible: !hasResults()"><b>No Results</b></div>
<div data-bind="visible: hasResults">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>FOO</td>
        <td>BAR</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: data">
      <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: FOO"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: BAR"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<br/>
<pre><code data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></code></pre>
```

Comment: THAT was incredibly helpfull and clear!
I had to adapt some tweaks, but I couldn't imagine a better answer. Thanks a LOT!